# Accessing Cell history (python, smartsheets)

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm looking for a way to access elements of a cell's history. I have used various iterations of the following code to get at the keys inside the cell history dict, but I'm (obviously) doing something wrong. When running the code as below I get this error - `TypeError: 'CellHistory' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Help! This is driving me crazy!

```
#get the cell history
action = smartsheet.Cells.get_cell_history(
    sheetid,
    sheet.rows[1].id,
    columns[1].id,
    include_all=True)

 revisions = action.data

#print out something from revision history
for rev in revisions:
    print rev['modifiedAt'] #breaks here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using the wrong attribute name and syntax in the `print` statement.  Try something like this instead:

```
#print out revision history
for rev in revisions:
    print(rev.modified_at)
    print(rev.modified_by.name)
    print('')
```

Comment: Tried `print (rev.modifiedAt)` - now getting "AttributeError: modifiedAt"
Any other ideas?

Comment: Tried modified_at (which, for reference, is NOT what's in the API documentation) and had success. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! For future reference:  any attributes described in the Smartsheet API documentation (which do not specifically appear in a Python code example) represent how the attributes appear in the API (JSON) requests/responses. The Python SDK uses Python variable naming conventions: "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability" (as described here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  For example, the raw API response may contain the attribute "modifiedAt" -- but when using this attribute via the Python SDK, you'll refer to it as "modified_at".